# Trading large volumes with penny profits per share

Tags: trading, stock-markets

Is there anything inherently wrong with this hypothetical trading strategy?

- Buy  10000 shares of stock at $10.00 for $100000 + $5 commission = $100005
- Sell 10000 shares of stock at $10.01 for $100100 - $5 commission = $100095
- Profit = $100095 - $100005 = $90

Note that this is likely **not** "high-frequency" trading, nor is it achieved programmatically.

It's easy enough to simply set two distinct limit orders to achieve this effect in regular "human" timescales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know the shares will go up after you buy? The ultimate risk in your scenario is that you buy at a peak, and then that peak is never reached again.

Over time, stock markets go up [more or less because there is a net increase in the overall production of the economy as time goes on]. However, you won't experience much of that gain, because you will be selling only after tiny amounts of profit have been achieved. So your upside is low, your plan is capital-expensive [because it requires you to have significant amount of cash available to make the initial purchase], and your downside [though unlikely] has massive risk.

Comment: This is a good point, but that sort of risk always exists when trading.

Comment: @ElleFie Risk always exists, but it's much lower when you have a diversified portfolio.

Comment: @ElleFie Your risk is theoretically very similar to 'regular' investing, with 2 important caveats: (1) In your example above, trading costs now eat ~5% of your profits, because you trade very frequently; and (2) by picking specific stocks / not remaining diversified [including, in most cases, investing in broad mutual funds etc.], your risk of picking a specifically tanking stock increase. If instead you just bought an Exchange Traded Fund of, say, the S&P 500, always selling after $100 of growth and then immediately rebuying, you could see how your strategy simply increases transaction costs.

Comment: Can the downvoter provide feedback/explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Currently my online savings account pays an interest rate of 1.25%.  With 100K, I can earn about $104 per month in that account.  No risk, no timing, no fuss.

So in theory you can make money by small changes in the valuations of stock.  However there are often better, risk free options for your money; or, there are much better options for returns with much less risk, but more than that of a bank account.

Comment: True, but this strategy, assuming even small (~0.1%) fluctuations in stock, will yield $90 **per day**, not per month.

Comment: That is not high-frequency trading?  If you think you can turn that kind of profit per day, you most will certainly go broke. You might make decent returns on 100 trades, but will then lose all profits, plus some of the 100K with one bad trade.

Comment: I see your point, but can't bracketed trades prevent large losses?

Comment: @ElleFie, ask yourself why this strategy isn't in broad use if it always works?